# How do we evaluate this general integral?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

From convolving two chi-squared distributions, I find the general integral
$$\int _0^yx^{\frac m 2 -1} \cdot (y-x)^{\frac n 2 -1}dx$$

Is there a way to evaluate this for arbitrary integers $n, m$? We can of course assume without loss of generality that $n>m$ or $n<m$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**.  By the change of variable
$$
t=\frac xy,\qquad dx=y \,dt,\qquad 
$$one gets
$$
\int _0^yx^{\frac m 2 -1} \cdot (y-x)^{\frac n 2 -1}dx=y^{\frac m 2+\frac n 2 -1}\int _0^1t^{\frac m 2 -1} \cdot (1-t)^{\frac n 2 -1}dt
$$ then one may use the [beta integral result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$
\int _0^1t^{a -1} \cdot (1-t)^{b -1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)},\quad a>0,\,b>0.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint. By letting $t=x/y$, we have that
$$\int _0^yx^{\frac m 2 -1} \cdot (y-x)^{\frac n 2 -1}dx=
y^{\frac m 2 +\frac n 2-1} \int _0^1t^{\frac m 2 -1
} \cdot (1-t)^{\frac n 2 -1}dt=y^{\frac m 2 +\frac n 2-1}B\left(\frac{m}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)$$
where $B(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).